# Why is !important not working on my stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to CSS/HTML and I need a little help with styling. So I have a CSS style sheet where I did something like this

```
p{
    color:black;
}
```

Then in my HTML, inside of my footer tag, I have a paragraph.

The problem I am having is that I want the color of the paragraph inside of my footer to be blue.

I tried doing something like this:

```
footer{
    color: blue !important;
}
```

but it didn't work so I was wondering how I can get just the paragraph in my footer to be blue because I want the rest of my paragraphs to be black.

If the !important method is the wrong approach I was wondering why? From my research, I thought it was supposed to override any previous styling.

Comment: So why not use `footer p { color: blue; }` without any `!important`? You should use `!important` as little as possible

Comment: So I literally just came on to say I found an example like that, and it did end up working. Thank you! I was just wondering why !important wouldn't achieve the same result

Comment: Because you are targeting 2 different elements, `p` and `footer` - You only use `!important` when you want to override a style of the **same type of element**

Answer (score 2):

## Answer:

> Why is !important not working on my stylesheet?

It is working perfectly as it is designed.

> How I can get just the paragraph in my footer to be blue

For this, please use the appropriate selector.

```
footer p{
   color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a bad practice
Try doing something like this
For your Footer

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer p {
 color: blue ;
}
```

Don't use important tags.